# Python: Relative Percentage Change

Tags: python, loops, numpy, pandas

I need help working out the % change between total values from one year in relation to the next, over a period of 213 days.

```
doy = df.DoY 
gpp = df.GPP_st_grams_half_hourly [(df.GPP_st_grams >0) & (df.SWDR>0)]
month= df.Month

gpp_gs = gpp[(doy >=60) & (doy<274)]

W2005_gpp=[]
for top in np.arange(60,273,1):
    W2005_gpp.append(gpp[(doy==top )].sum())


Year_difference =[]
#    ABSOLUTE DIFFERENCE
for i in np.arange(0,213,1):
    Year_difference.append((W2003_gpp[i]-W2005_gpp[i]))

Relative_difference=[]
for i in np.arange(0,213,1):
    Relative_difference.append((((W2003_gpp[i]-W2005_gpp[i])/W2005_gpp[i])*100))
```

W2003 is defined and looped in exactly the same way further up in the script.

I am just a Geography student and have a very poor understanding of programming!

This is what the df looks like

```
Data columns (total 38 columns):
Year                       17520  non-null values
Month                      17520  non-null values
DoY                        17520  non-null values
Time                       17520  non-null values
DTIME                      17520  non-null values
GPP_f                      17520  non-null values
GPP_f_grams_half_hourly       17520  non-null values
dtypes: float64(35), int64(3)
```

I want a plot of % change between each total value on the y axis over each day. Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you share a sample of what `df` looks like, and what you want your result to look like?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong with the above code? What is the expected result and what are you getting instead?

Comment: The column descriptions fro `df` don't help -- what we need is a sample file we can test your code on, and some sample output -- a snippet of what you're expecting to see/trying to produce. We just need 5-10 lines.

Comment: It looks like you are using a very old version of Pandas.